# Why can I not edit the Mesh name in field created with row.prop(obj, "data")

Tags: python, scripting, interface

With the following code I can read out the name of a mesh data block.

```
row.prop(obj, "data")
```

And with the following code I can read out the name of the object.

```
row.prop(obj, "name")
```

But I noticed that I cannot edit the mesh data name only the object name.

[image]

Here is the code from Blender that generated the mesh data block UI.

```
class DATA_PT_context_mesh(MeshButtonsPanel, Panel):
    bl_label = ""
    bl_options = {'HIDE_HEADER'}
    COMPAT_ENGINES = {'BLENDER_RENDER', 'BLENDER_GAME'}

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        ob = context.object
        mesh = context.mesh
        space = context.space_data

        if ob:
            layout.template_ID(ob, "data")
        elif mesh:
            layout.template_ID(space, "pin_id")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of Objects as containers, which can contain *Curve data* or *Mesh data* (and a few other kinds).

`obj.data` will refer to the *Mesh* or the *Curve* of the object. You would need to do the following to display the mesh's name

```
row.prop(obj.data, "name")
```

Or replicating what the standard panels do (with or without the icon).

```
    obj = context.object

    col = layout.column()
    if obj.data:
        col.prop(obj.data, "name")
        col.prop(obj.data, "name", icon="OUTLINER_DATA_" + obj.type)
    else:
        col.label('An empty selected')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank your very much. I learned a lot in the past days. I start to understand now how my students must feel when I teach Blender and they are new to it. There is a lot to take in.